# How to rewrite a file in .htaccess located in the /blog directory to the root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried so much, but i still can't rewrite a file in .htaccess located in the /blog directory to the root.

The url in the directory is

```
site.com/blog/319-2/
```

desired url

```
site.com/support/
```

htaccess is in the root & blog directory.

Root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

And Blog directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I should also mention that this domain is an addon domain not a primary just in-case that would have any influence...

Comment: public_html is home of my primary domain and then public_html/addondomain.com is for the addon.

Comment: I don't wan't to redirect at-all, i want to rewrite it... So that it could be accessed from either url, a-bit like when removing the .php suffix...

Comment: from addon to addon. When i tried the 2nd rule i had an Internal server error message...

Comment: Sure and thanks - Will do first thing tomorrow - It's 5AM Here ! HAHA

Comment: I am afraid that what you want is not possible, WordPress get the page based on the URI, if you internally rewrite `/support/` to `/blog/319-2/` it would lose the URI and would not know what content to display. Perhaps you could create support as a page and serve the content you need?

Comment: You mean /blog/319-2/ to /support/ ? That's what i wanted to do... Similar to how i can serve folder/page or folder/page.html...

Comment: You said on the comments of my answer you want to show the URL `addondomain.com/support/` with the content of `addondomain.com/blog/319-2/`. You have to decide yourself. Your exact words `site.com/support/ and have it serve the content of site.com/blog/319-2/`

Comment: YES! - site.com/support/ and have it serve the content of site.com/blog/319-2/..."You said on the comments of my answer you want to show the URL addondomain.com/support/ with the content of addondomain.com/blog/319-2/" The same thing...

Comment: No its not the same ;) however this you won't be able to do and I've explained above why. At least to my knowledge that would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect that URL instead of the whole directory use

```
RewriteRule ^blog/319-2/?$ /support/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: @user2626526, use a redirect rule instead. Check update. Do you want blog/319-2/some-page.html to be served from /support/some-page.html i.e. sub pages rewrite as well?

Comment: The truth is i don't know the what the file name is, as its just a wordpress page, i don't know whether its htaccess adding the trailing slash or whether its a directory.

Comment: Sorry, you're quite vague about what happens when you apply this rule. I would suggest you update the question with the source url used; the url you're being redirected to and your expected url. The more info you share the faster and accurate the help you would get.